# How to find biggest array value in an arraylist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with elements in the following format. What I tried is, I collected all the `edtime` and placed them in to `edtimearray`. I am trying to find the biggest one among the arrays values. I have used something like this. but I get the message "object doesn't support this action" .

```
var edtimearray = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= obj.length - 1; i++) {
    edtimearray = obj[i].edtime;
    if (i == obj.length - 1) {
        var arrayMax = Function.prototype.apply.bind(Math.max, edtimearray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can simplify that a lot:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, obj.map(function(o) { return o.edtime; }));
```

So you start with an array of objects, and you want an array of property values from those objects. JavaScript (regrettably) doesn't have a standard "pluck" method, so you use `.map()` to build an array of those property values.

Now what you want to do is invoke `Math.max()` with those property values as arguments, like

```
var max = Math.max(value1, value2, ... )
```

That's where `.apply()` comes in. When you *want* an argument list, but what you've *got* is an array, `.apply()` is your friend. Thus we just need to invoke `Math.max()` with `.apply()` — and pass in `Math` as the `this` value, because some native functions are picky about that — and then the array as the second argument.

Comment: you want t me to pass only edtime or edtimearray  ? Since there is a bunch of value in arraylist and I need to pick it from there.

Comment: @jfriend00 yes sorry I was in the middle of making dinner for a kid :) typing in more stuff now

Comment: @jfriend00 says something about my life I guess

Answer (score -2):

Here's a good way to get the largest element in an array:

```
var arr = []; // some array with values
arr.sort().reverse(); // sort array ascending order
var largestVal = arr[0];
```

Comment: That's actually the lowest value. Surely not the biggest.

Comment: @AxelAmthor well the default sort order is ascending, so by reversing that you end up with the biggest value at the beginning of the list.

Comment: this will return the largest value in an array because of the `reverse()` call.

Comment: @Pointy aah I see, and that's why you call it `lowestVal` ;-)

Comment: doh, that was just a typo on my part

Comment: This is wrong, `sort` will sort lexicographically, do `arr.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})`

Comment: Plus, the OP is trying to find the largest `.edtime` property in an array of objects so you can't use plain `.sort()` on an array of objects anyway without at least a custom callback that targets the `.edtime` property, but the whole idea of sorting just to find the max or min value seems like way overkill to me and it's destructive to the original array too.